# How To fix context.getSystemService(class) for api 21?

Tags: java, android, android-jobscheduler

I was following the video for `JobScheduler`:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XFN3MrnNhZA

But lint was giving me that `context.getSystemService(class)` is `api 23.` So am I missing something or did android change something with there api?

Note: Mostly wondering if `JobScheduler` was introduced in `api 21` how would it work without `getSystemService(Class)`

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android. Yes it was in api 21. You could use FireBaseJobDispatcher instead

Comment: @Raghunandan Please consider writing this as an answer, otherwise the question may remain open indefinitely.

Comment: I figured my problem but i can't type an answer for like 2 days i think. I was using getSystemService(class) should used getSystemService(String). But gonna use your since it is what i wanted.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thanks to Reghunandan I found a better solution for my problem by using:

> github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android

But if any body got same problem here is the mistake:

```
getSystemService(Class) API 23
```

Should be:

```
getSystemService(String) API 1

getSystemService(context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) API 21
```

Comment: In addition, I had to cast it into a `jobScheduler` object as follows. `JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);`

Comment: Official docs: [getSystemService(Class)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getSystemService(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) | [getSystemService(String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getSystemService(java.lang.String))

Comment: In Kotlin, [cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#unsafe-cast-operator) it as follows: `getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager`

Answer (score 6):

Came here with a similar problem for NotificationManager. What I ended up doing was

```
 val notificationManager =
                ContextCompat.getSystemService(
                    requireContext(),
                    NotificationManager::class.java
                ) as NotificationManager
```